# Spring + jsp + javascript - spring:hasBindErrors

Tags: java, javascript, spring, jsp

I have code:

```
<spring:hasBindErrors name="formTest">
    <c:forEach items="${errors.globalErrors}" var="error">
      <spring:message code="${error.code}" /><br/>
    </c:forEach>
</spring:hasBindErrors>
```

So I pass `${errors}` from Spring.

How can I check in JavaScript whether errors exist not? I tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var NO_ERRORS = ${errors.errorCount? true :false};
</script>
```

But I always have: **false** (even if errors are exists)

I tried too:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var NO_ERRORS = <c:if test="{empty errors}">true</c:if><c:if test="{not empty errors}">false</c:if>;
    </script>
```

And: (here I always **true**)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var NO_ERRORS = ${empty errors? true :false};
    </script>
```

---

Ok I have:

```
<spring:hasBindErrors name="formModel">
            <c:set var="isError" value="${errors.errorCount == 0}" />
            <c:if test="${isError}">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                IS_ERRORS = false;
                </script>
            </c:if>
    </spring:hasBindErrors>
```

But it is wrong, because does not work this: `<c:set var="isError" value="${errors.errorCount == 0}" />` if I change to `<c:set var="isError" value="${errors.errorCount > 0}" />` is good, but why firstly solution does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var NO_ERRORS = <c:if test="{empty errors}">true</c:if><c:if test="{not empty errors}">false</c:if>;
```

assuming you save `errors` only if error exists. Else you can check based on `errors.errorCount==0` and `errors.errorCount>0`

Comment: Where must I paste your code? Because in js file, I have error:SyntaxError: syntax error 

var NO_ERRORS = ;

Comment: From above code it seems there is no separate JS file, and hence you will have to paste that code inside your <script> tag. It's weird that both c-ifs are evaluating to false.